# changing style of paragraph in dropzone-material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how to change style of material-ui-dropzone component using makeStyles?

my useStyle is:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    DropzoneArea: {                
        fontWeight: 10,
        margin:0,
        padding:0                
    }
}

and in app.js i use this:

<DropzoneArea                                
    acceptedFiles={['image/*']}
    maxFileSize={10000000}
    filesLimit={1}                                                                                   
    dropzoneClass={classes.DropzoneArea}                        
/>
```

Comment: Based on a first glance at the Dropzone docs and src, I would expect what you have to be applied to the dropzone component. When this renders do you see your classname in the html? (I didn't trace the src all the way down to the output in react-dropzone; I'm assuming the props get passed down.)

Comment: no there is not:(

Comment: this library doesn't provide a good way of doing that. they only provide you way to style the container, but you won't be able to style the text from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can style it with makeStyles.

The best way is to grab the class name of the p element from inspector and style it. It worked for me.

```
.MuiDropzoneArea-text {
        .....Your style here
}
```

Mark the style with **"!important"** if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following class:

```
dropzoneParagraphClass="dropzone-text"
```

In your .css file you can style the text:

```
.dropzone-text {
    font-size: 100px !important; /* or something */
}
```